# sqlplus can not connect to oracle using information in tnsnames.ora

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus, tnsnames, oracle12c

I can login by

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

then I start the intance using startup, I also can start PDB using

```
startup pluggable database pdborcl
```

In the terminal, echo $ORACLE_SID gets ora12cr1

But I cannot login by using

```
sqlplus  /@ora12cr1 as sysdba
```

I got ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied. Below is my tnsnames.ora:

```
ORA12CR1=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.cn.oracle.com)
    )
  )

PDBORCL =
 (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl.cn.oracle.com)
     )
 )
```

The oracle 12cr1 is install in my local machine.

lsnrctl status gets:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on 11-SEP-2013 23:02:57

Copyright (c) 1991, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                11-SEP-2013 22:40:09
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 22 min. 48 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "orcl.cn.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ora12cr1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.cn.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ora12cr1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdborcl.cn.oracle.com" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ora12cr1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

SQL> show pdbs

    CON_ID CON_NAME           OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
     3 PDBORCL            READ WRITE NO
```

and

```
alter session set container = pdborcl
```

also works.

Comment: So, what happens when you actually pass in a username/password on the sqlplus command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try

sqlplus /@localhost.localdomain/orcl.cn.oracle.com as sysdba

if that's the service you want to log on to (not sure if I understand your question entirely).

Comment: It didn't work adona9. Actually, I have tried sqlplus /@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl.cn.oracle.com))) as sysdba. Still failed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
sqlplus sys@pdborcl as sysdba
```

and entering the password.

```
show con_name;
```

yields the value

```
CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDBORCL
```

Answer (score 0):

using `/ AS SYSDBA` will work as it did in previous releases at the `container database` level (CDB). but It's NOT able to connect to the `pluggable database` (PDB) without password by sqlplus.

The simplest way to achieve this is to continue to connect using "/ as SYSDBA", but to set the specific container in your script using the `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER` command.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF

ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = pdb1;

-- Perform actions as before...
SHOW CON_NAME;

EXIT;
EOF
```

you also can refer this article for more information [Multitenant : Running Scripts Against Container Databases (CDBs) and Pluggable Databases (PDBs) in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-runing-scripts-cdb-and-pdb-12cr1.php)